# How to stop displaying "Error - The server was unable to process the request" - IBM MobileFirst 7.1.0

Tags: connection, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am developing app for Android and IPhone using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1.0.

`WL.Client.Connect` is used inside `wlcommoninit()`.

Still in few cases, I am able to see the below error dialog.

[image]

I am not able to exactly reproduce when I am getting this error dialog.

The logcat is attached [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx4uFCvvg_AqQk1RUE84UUtaZms).

But is there any way that we can block showing this dialog to the user?

Comment: Why not actually sure what you're referring to?

Comment: Please be clear with your question.

Comment: @S.A.NortonStanley: The question is very simple. How to stop displaying the Error Dialog? I am able to see the dialog even after using WL.Client.Connect in wlcommoninit().

Comment: @IdanAdar Please refer the question.

Comment: Add a photo of the error and clear reproduction steps.

Comment: @IdanAdar Edited the question with screen shot. But still not able to reproduce the exact scenario

Comment: Is the issue happening on both Android and iOS ? That might point to a server issue? Are you trying a simple WL.Client.connect() and that gives this issue? What does the server log say when this issue happens?

Comment: @VivinK I have tested only in Android. The log says the app is not connected to server. The onFailure method of WL.Client.Connect got triggered.

Comment: Post the Logcat from the Android device when you recreate the issue.

Comment: @VivinK Logcat is attached in question. Please find it.

Comment: Logcat shows:
11-09 14:20:36.527: D/HttpPostRequestSender(23133): WLHybridRequestSender.run in WLHybridRequestSender.java:42 :: Sending request http://192.9.200.105:10080/Sample/apps/services/api/Sample/android/init

11-09 14:20:37.387: E/NONE(23133): [/apps/services/api/Sample/android/init] failure. state: 404, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.

Verify the URL and connectivity. It could be intermittent connectivity loss

Comment: @VivinK URL is proper and the app is able to connect as my worklight server is down. But my point is when the app is not able to connect to the server it should trigger only onFailure of WL.Client.Connect but instead it calls onFailure method at the same time it displays the default error dialog from server too. How do we stop displaying the error dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You could debug the application code to see which function is triggered when this specific dialog is displayed and then override the function by declaring it in your own code and simply keep it empty. In theory this should then not display it.

There is no built-in/provided option to simply not display it.